# ADB will only recognize devices once per USB port

Tags: usb, android, adb

So I am trying to connect to my phone via ADB and this normally works. But once I disconnect the device and connect it again to the same USB port ADB won't find the device. According to lsusb it is still there. The filesystem can be mounted and files can be transferred.

If I disconnect the device again and use another USB port it works again. Until I disconnect the device. Afterwards I will have to pick yet another port.

Now I am running out of ports to connect to and this can only be fixed by restarting the system.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem or knows a way to completely reset an USB port? Or is this purely ADB's problem? Does the process have some kind of cache that can be reset?

What I already tried:

- Killing and restarting the adb server
- Checking the user groups
- Changing the USB connection mode
- Switching the Host mode (doesn't work, phone has to be host)
- Toggling the USB debugging mode
- Restarting the udev service

I am out of ideas. Restarting the computer every odd hour just to get USB to run for a while is a bit annoying.

OS: 18.04 / 4.15.0-45-generic

Comment: what kernel and OS version do you have... in a Terminal paste  : `. /etc/os-release && echo $VERSION_ID && uname -r` then copy the ouput with ctrl+shift+C and edit your post to add it.

Comment: I have a similar problem on Gentoo, with kernel 4.14.8. adb causes havoc with USB everywhere and triggers constant resets *on other devices*.